# How to open Google Maps (or alternative) navigation with multiple destinations?

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, maps

I'm working on a cross platform (iOS & Android) app that requires the user to follow a (possibly closed) path made of several destinations.

So far it seems that my best option is to find a way to open Google Maps with a URL like this: https://www.google.com/maps/dir/San+Jose,+CA/GooglePlex/San+Francisco,+CA

Besides the fact that such url opens the browser first and not the app directly, Google Maps doesn't enter the "navigation" mode.

I analyzed the SDK and there doesn't seem to be a way to instantiate a path with multiple destinations.

Is there a way to achieve navigation on multiple destinations in Google Maps? If not, any alternative with "navigation" mode?

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted, the question seems valid and I'm wondering myself too if you could trigger a google maps navigation call with multiple waypoints and not just a destination waypoint.

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can achieve navigation in multiple direction
1) in navigation map first it has been showing one direction , there your calling one api, check that api you will get multiple direction data, just you have to parse the all data by using loop and need to do custom implementation.

Comment: sorry I don't uderstand very well what you mean. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/, like this u will find url in your code, just hit that url in browser u will get json, in that json u will get multiple routes data, just u need to parse data.